# Python to handle color to terminal and also in file

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, vim

I am printing Pass and Fail on terminal with color on terminal and some output file.

terminal output:

```
  Parameter                Output                   Result
  ------------             ------------             -------
  Timer Enabled            Enabled                  Passed
```

File output (Opened using vim editor):

```
  Parameter                Output                   Result
  ------------             ------------             -------
  Timer Enabled            Enabled                  ^[[92mPassed^[[0m
```

In python I used below code:

```
 HEADER = '\033[95m'
 OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
 OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
 WARNING = '\033[93m'
 FAIL = '\033[91m'
 ENDC = '\033[0m'
 BOLD = '\033[1m'
 UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
```

Code execution happen in linux machine and file open will done in windows machine (word pad or notepad++) and linux like vim editor.

Now i need help, when i open file from vim or windows word pad. I do not want to see color code like "^[[92mPassed^[[0m" its too ugly. Could  any one help me the best options to achieve the results

Comment: Libraries like [click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) with automatically remove ANSI codes if the output is to a file. It also provides a nice interface for formatting/colouring text.

Answer (score 1):

If the file output is generated by way of

```
python script.py > foo.txt
```

you can use `os.isatty(1)` (where 1 is the file handle for standard output) to figure out whether the output is attached to a terminal (as opposed to a file). If it's attached to a terminal, don't output the color control codes.

You can also naturally also strip the control codes post-fact with something like

```
text = re.sub('\033\\[\d+m', '', text)
```

Comment: python script.py > foo.txt again print color code in file.. os.isaaty(1) i do not understand now i read docs and may be striping is good option

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
class Colors:
HEADER = '\033[95m'
OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
WARNING = '\033[93m'
FAIL = '\033[91m'
ENDC = '\033[0m'

def disable(self):
    self.HEADER = ''
    self.OKBLUE = ''
    self.OKGREEN = ''
    self.WARNING = ''
    self.FAIL = ''
    self.ENDC = ''
    # Prints to terminal
    print (Colors.FAIL + "This is the sample text..." + Colors.ENDC)     
    # Handles text without color code in file.  
    orig_stdout = sys.stdout
    f = open('out.txt', 'a')
    sys.stdout = f
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
        print (color.FAIL + "This is the sample text..." + color.ENDC)

color = Colors()
color.disable()
```

`disable` will help you get the output in a file without that ugly color codes.

I have just created a sample code. You can change and reuse it according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Try using *colorama* package in python for text colour & has cross platform support across Windows & Linux. It can also be used in conjunction with existing ANSI libraries like Termcolor. This approach would be better than manually printing ASCII sequences for text colouring on terminals.

```
    from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
    print(Fore.RED + 'Red Text')
    print(Back.GREEN + 'background in Green')
    print(Style.DIM + 'Dim Text')
    print(Style.RESET_ALL)
    print('Normal Text')
```